# How to set the Exec when bash command is too long?

Tags: desktop, exec

The desktop file works fine:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Action
Name=unrar zip or rar file 
Profiles=unrar

[X-Action-Profile unrar]
MimeTypes=inode/directory
Exec=bash -c "unar /home/test.rar  -o  /tmp;zenity --info --text \"extract rar file into target\""
```

I want to split the `Exec=` to two lines:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Action
Name=unrar zip or rar file 
Profiles=unrar

[X-Action-Profile unrar]
MimeTypes=inode/directory
Exec=bash -c "unar /home/test.rar  -o  /tmp;
              zenity --info --text \"extract rar file into target\""
```

The desktop file don't take effect ,how can spllit the `Exec=` statement to two lines?

Comment: I'm not sure it's allowed/possible: https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-1.1.html

Comment: Move the complex command into a script and call that from your desktop entry